# MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am new to docker and trying to create a Dockerfile for ASP.NET Core application. Can someone suggest what changes do I require?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY Presentation/ECCP.Web/ *.csproj ./  
RUN dotnet restore  
COPY . ./  
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out  

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]
```

I am facing the following error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use
>   because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
>   The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like your work dirctory contains both .csproj and .sln files. Try to specify the .sln file in the command. 
Run

```
dotnet publish your-solution-file.sln -c Release -o out
```

I had the same error message with dotnet build and this solves it.

By the way, since .NET Core 2.0 the dotnet restore command is run implicitly, so you may skip it.

Comment: exactly what I needed thanks! I do have one concern about adding 100% of the project files because I might have things in there I don't want to ship every time. Not sure how to call that out here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bitbucket-pipelines.yml in a Bitbucket pipeline ensure you have the following line in the step where you run Sonar scanner.

```
- dotnet dotcover test <your-solution-filename-here>.sln -c Release --dcReportType=HTML
```